# Tensorflow encoding png

Tags: python, image-processing, tensorflow

Tesorflow novice here. I'm trying to load a png, run it through `tf.image.resize_images()`, then save the resized image back to disk.

```
import tensorflow as tf

file = tf.read_file('./img/img-01.png')
img = tf.image.decode_png(file, channels=3)
large = tf.image.resize_images(img, size=(40, 70))
loss = tf.cast(large, dtype=tf.uint16)

encoded = tf.image.encode_png(loss)
write = tf.write_file('./out.png', encoded)

with tf.Session() as sess:
    sess.run(write)
```

The I/O operations seem to work, but this is what I'm getting:

Input image (4x7px):

[image]

Expected output image (40x70px): (Same as input, but scaled)

Actual output image: (40x70px): (every pixel set to `(0, 0, 0)`

[image]

### Edit

Here's the output of `encoded.eval()`:

`` b'\x89PNG\r\n\x1a\n\x00\x00\x00\rIHDR\x00\x00\x00F\x00\x00\x00(\x10\x02\x00\x00\x00\x9c"\xc7\xba\x00\x00\x02\x9fIDATx\x9c\xedZ\xb1N%1\x0c\x9c;=(\xa0\x80\x02\n\xf8\xffo\x83\x02\n(\xa0\x80\xe2\xae\x18\xedf\x847\x91\xd7\xe1Vg\x92)\xac\xa7l6\xe3\xac\xe3(\xe3\x97_\xf8\x03\xe2\x0ew\x00\xeeq\x1f\xf8\xfd\x80\x87\xd5>\xe2q\xb5\xdaR\xeb\xe3\xe7\xd2\x96\x1ao\xed\xb7m\xd9\xcb\xd5\x9eo\x8d\xcb\xb6\x07pZ\xe9op\x03\xe0\nW\x00.p\x01\xe0\x0cgk\xbf\x0f|\x00x\xc7;\x80\x17\xbc|y\xfa\x8cg\x00\xafx]\xfb\xb0?\xc1\x9e\x1c\xf3\x1a\xd7\x00>\xf1\xb9>\xf5\xf3r\xfcs\x9c7xud\xf6\xe4\x98\x1c_\xbdj\xf3r\x1c\xff|\x95\xb7=\xdf\x00NXV\x07\xdd\xf58M\xe7\xb4\x9d\xd3\xf08\xcd\xf1\t~\xc4\xd1x\x03(\x99\xc4Ai/q\xb9\xe9\xf4\x1b\xde6\xa7\xa1\x96}\xac\xd3\x1c\xd3Nc4\xde\x00J&q k\xad\x8b:\x01\xae\x0en#lWk]\xd4\t\xb0\xcfh\xbc\x01\x94Lj\xc3\xba\xe2\x87\xfd\x04~\x8c\xc6\xbb\x89\x92I\xb5\xd5\xe1\xb1\xb5U\xd9\xb6\xedU\xf9Sy\x83Ab&\xd9}V\x93]\xd3_\x9f\xd2\xda\xfd]\x93]\xd3_\x9f\xd2\x8e\xc6\x1b\x0c\x123IO,\x84&\xbb\xee\xcb\xec\xa3VOJ\x84&\xbb\xee\xcb\xda\x93\xc7\xd3\xd1x\x03(\x99\xe4?\xdb\xd0\xd1\'<aQ\x0cV\x15\xd5\xce6t\xf7\x16\xb7X\x94\xcah\xbc\x01\x94L\xb2\xce\xe9\x1ej\x9d\xa6\xbb\xaa\xa2U<\xea4\xb4\x9d\xab\x89\xee*\xaf\x8a\xd6\xb6\x98m\xf3\xb6\xc5\xac\x9f\xd7\x8aY?\xaf\x15\xb3\x96w\x17NXJ\x17t\x82\x0e\xb5\xab\x06\x1e\xf5\xae\x01\xde[\xad\xf8\xae\xaaAO\xb5\xa2\xa7J\xd2\xaeV\x04P\x82\xa4{\xee1\xea\x9d\x1fq4\xde\x00NXR8\xa3z\xcf\xc8\x1b@\tRLE\xf3-\xae\xaf#\xd5{^\xde\x00\xcav\xd7FF\xf5\x9e\x91w\x13%\x932\xaa\xf7\x8c\xbc\xc1 1\x932\xaa\xf7\x8c\xbc]A\xe2A\xf3H\xf5\xce\xb7F\xe3\r\xa0lw\xfe\xb3\xcd\xf7\xaa\xf7\xd1x\x03(A"<\xea\xddS5\xa8U+\xf6\xaa\xf7\x9e\xaaAO\xb5\xc2S5\xe8\xa9V\xec\xc2\xbc\xe30\xc0\x1d\x871\xab\x06=\xbc\x01\xcc;\x0eG\xf3\x06\xd0{\xc7\x81}\xda\x9a\xa0\xa6\xde\xdbz\xe5\xa7\xf2\x060\xef8\xfc_\xbc\x9b\xe8\xbd\xe3\xd0\xaee\xfd;\xf5\x9e\x977\x18\xa4y\xc7!\xc1\x1d\x07\x06IO,\x84GE\xf7\xfc\xe7O;\x1ao\x00e\xbb\xb3\xf2\xf3\x98\xff\xfcG\xe3\r`\xdeq\x88W\r\x0e\xbb\xe3\xf0;\xf6\xda\xc4\x91\x98AJ\x80\x19\xa4\x04\x98AJ\x80\x19\xa4\x04\x98AJ\x80\x19\xa4\x04\x98AJ\x80\x19\xa4\x04\xf8\x0b\x01&\xe1\xe0B\x84\xb8\n\x00\x00\x00\x00IEND\xaeB`\x82' ``

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was that I was casting the tensor created by `tf.resize_images()` to `tf.uint16`, but it had to be `tf.uint8`.